# GPU usage monitor for FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, monitoring, gpu, gnome-system-monitor

I am using FreeBSD on a personal desktop computer, and a nvidia GTX 1650 GPU.
In my gnome system monitor (similar to task manager of MS Windows), I am able to monitor all the resources, including all the processor cores, RAM, swap memory, and other stuff. But GPU is not visible there.

Is there any tool for FreeBSD to see the GPU activity/usage?
GUI based is preferred, but CLI is ok as well.
I did a lot of research, but could not find anything to monitor GPU usages.

I do not want to over-clock the GPU. I want to only monitor it.

Comment: Is there such a tool for Linux to begin with?

Comment: @arrowd yes, but, hm, it's very specific to the individual acceleration provider.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same tools as under Linux, the program you're looking for is probably `nvidia-smi`.

Comment: @rohit4444 Agreed, `man nvidia-smi` has lots of info.